# Significance of the many unusual names?

Tags: analysis, pacific-rim

I might go the risk of a slightly opinionated question here, but it seems to me that [*Pacific Rim*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1663662/) employs quite some unusual forenames for many of its major characters, e.g. *Raleigh*, *Yancy*, *Stacker*, *Newton*, *Hercules* (or *"Herc"*), compared to the more or less Anglo origin of those characters. So **is there any further significance to or reason for all those unusual names or was this just an arbitrary decision?** (Or maybe those forenames aren't as weird as I think them to be, yet they struck me as pretty remarkable in their frequency of occurrence.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think they were just having fun making those names up. In an [interview](http://badassdigest.com/2013/07/12/the-badass-interview-guillermo-del-toro-gets-spoilery-on-pacific-rim/), Guillermo del Toro said:

> Travis is truly a genius at world creation and naming. He came up with Jaeger and kaiju. We shared robot names - I put half, he put half - but Hercules Hansen? That’s a fucking name! Stacker Pentecost. He had something weird for Raleigh, I changed it to Raleigh Becket. It was originally Raleigh Antrobus. What a fucking name! It sounded like a suppository.

[The imaginative naming of robots was used as a part of a promotion campaign](http://www.uproxx.com/gammasquad/2013/07/pacific-rim-parody-meme-improved-jaeger-names/), which I see as a further confirmation that this was done purely for fun.

A movie like "Pacific Rim" really must avoid taking itself seriously, because it'd make it look absurd. So, a healthy dose of goofiness is more than welcome, and the names fit in that perfectly.